# How is cacheable able to get method argument value by using its name

Tags: java, spring

How can I view the implementation for @Cacheable. I want to find out how they are able to get the name of a method's argument and obtain its actual value at runtime.

For example:

```
    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "name", key = "#key")
    public String method(String key){
        //some logic  
        return null; 
    }
```

How is cacheable able to get the value of the argument key? I need to implement this in a custom annotation and unable to find any references. Simply trying to click on the @Cacheable leads me to the annotation implementation and not able to find a way to see how it is getting parsed.

Been snooping around on documentation and unfortunately not able to find any reference either. Don't see any similar question here either which talks about this. Please assist or advice how I could go about implementing a custom annotation and read the method's argument value as a name, not an index. Thanks.

Comment: I am assuming Spring is reading method parameters via Reflection. You can check the code at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache

Comment: https://blogs.sap.com/2016/12/28/how-does-annotation-cacheable-work/ hope this works for u

Answer (score 0):

The way the `@Cacheable` annotation works is complex because it's not just about getting the values in runtime, and that's it. It has a lot of things running in the background.

The way it gets value in runtime is by using reflection and AOP, a good start point is to debug/review the [cache package](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache) and the [base class for the cash aspect](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheAspectSupport.java) both on GitHub.

Comment: I am only looking for the part where it is able to get the argument's value via the name instead of index. Wiil have a look at the above. Thanks.